# What was the first story to be set in the future?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

Lots of science fiction stories today are set in the future. Sometimes they give a specific date, like they'll say "AD 2532". Sometimes it's not spelled out but it's obvious, like I'm not sure if Star Trek ever gave an actual date, but it's obviously supposed to be a few hundred years from now.

What was the first story to do this?

By "the future" I mean the writer's future, not necessarily ours. If you know of a story written in AD 1000 but set in AD 1500, in which the writer talks about amazing future technologies like the printing press, and discovery of a new continent to the west, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.

I'm sure we could get into quibbles over definitions. I'm looking for "stories", things that could be called "science fiction stories" in some broad sense. I want to rule out statements of future intent, like, "Next year we will attack the Ottoman Empire", or simple predictions of consequences, like, "Ceasar, if you don't reinforce Gaul, within five years the barbarians will invade."

Arguably there could be a fine line between a warning and a story. Like, "If you continue on this course, I see a time, maybe ten or twenty years from now, when the barbarians will invade. Perhaps it will begin with a barbarian horde attacking the outpost at ..." At some point a discussion of what could happen in a hypothetical situation could cross the line into being a story. If you know of borderline examples, feel free to mention them.

I'd also exclude stories that talk about the passage of time without specifying the start and end points in any way. I'm thinking, for example, of Rip van Winkle: A man is put under a spell that makes him sleep for 20 years. But I don't think the story ever says whether it starts in the present and he wakes up 20 years in the future, or he started 20 years ago and wakes up in the present, or if the start and end are both in the past, or, more likely, that it just doesn't matter to the story, because it's not about social or technological change over time but about one person's personal and family life.

Let's also rule out religious prophecies. The accuracy and significance of such prophecies is a fascinating question -- and probably more important than the question I'm asking! -- but that's a totally different subject, and wouldn't be within the scope of this forum anyway.

Comment: Before people start complaining about this being too broad or too opinion based, let me preemptively throw my hat in the ring that this is a Good Question.   There will be borderline cases, but I think we can get an answer to the gist of the question.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Hmm, I tried to make the question concrete with no room for opinion, beyond possible quibbles over borderline cases, which I think could apply to almost any question. I guess we'll see what the reaction is.

Comment: "I tried to think of the most harmless thing. Something I loved from my childhood. Something that could never ever possibly destroy us. Mr. Stay Puft!"

Comment: In other words, stories that are set in the future relative to the writer, written for reasons other than immediate practical implementation or instruction, have a narrative, and include technology not available at the time they were written?

Comment: @MishaRosnach Yes, except that I wouldn't include the clause about technology. If, for example, someone wrote a story in 1600 about civilization collapsing in 1700, there might well be no new technology, but it would be a "story set in the future".

Comment: @Jay:   Like I said, I have no problem with this question; I like it.   But there is sometimes a tendency for what I at least internally classify as "VTC because we can (i.e. I can tell a story about why this is violating some perceived rule, not because the gist is actually bad)" and then there can be clear bandwagon voting behavior.   And once the bandwagon starts, it's nearly impossible to reverse.    It happens to be my pet peeve, so I was just trying to help out preemptively.   I am glad to see there is support in this case (based on upvotes on my initial comment).

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/1491/large/

Comment: I assume you also want to rule out religious prophecies which have been deemed to have come true, as there is always the question of whether a text that is thousands of years old and predicted events 400 years in its future was really written when it claimed to be.

Comment: Rip van WInkle starts and ends in the past, as the author knew about the American Revolution.

Comment: @MathiasFoster I wanted to say that too :-) specifically, the in-story references seem to indicate that Rip van Winkle slept from 1776 (or perhaps 1775) to 1796. The story itself was written in the 1810s, so yes, both ends are in the past.

Comment: I would like to mention [Ragnarök](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k) as a special case, since it's not so much a "religious prophecy" ("do this and find salvation" / "do this or you will be damned"), but a rather peculiar telling of the future fate of gods, told in a way that makes it none too clear whether it *will* happen, *might* happen, or already *has* happened... (because Germanic mythology is circular, not linear like e.g. Christian myths) It's religious, anyway, hence a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @DevSolar To the extent that my opinion as the OP matters -- and apparently others are interested in the question so I don't suppose my opinion is definitive any more -- by ruling out religious prophecies I meant, rule out prophecies that are given by divine inspiration or claimed to be so, on the reasoning that: (a) They are not really "stories" but more like promises and/or warnings. I wasn't really looking for "based on our analysis, we predict the stock market will rise by 200 points next year" either.  ...

Comment: ... (b) If the prophecy is really of divine or otherwise supernatural origin, it's not about human creativity. Of course a non-believer in the given religion would say it's all about human imagination, and I wanted to avoid getting into a religious argument.

Comment: Several good and interesting answers, but I can only pick one to award the gold medal. Sorry FuzzyBoots, yours may be the actual right answer, but as I say, had to pick one. Now I want to check out the stories mentioned.

Comment: @Jay: In that case Ragnarök would actually qualify, since Germanic paganism doesn't claim "divine inspiration" in the first place, and the stories neither promise nor warn, just state. ;-) Nevermind, I just wanted to point out an interesting sidenote.

Comment: @devsolar Despite being of Norwegian ancestry, I've only read snippets of Germanic/Norse mythology. Mostly what's in the back of Edith Hamilton. So I don't claim to have an informed opinion on this subject. (Of course, most people don't let total ignorance prevent them from having strong opinions on a subject, but.)

Comment: I think this question is too broad because some scribe in ancient Egypt could have written a story about what will happen to him tomorrow as if it were real. BUT I think it could easily be made on-topic by specifying a beginning cut-off date like "since the printing press was invented" or "since the concept of publishing was created, and only published works" or something.

Comment: I don't see why religious prophecy falls outside the realm of fantasy. Are not prophecies very common literary devices for millennia now? The first that comes to my mind is Oedipus Rex, circa 300BC. The story begins with a short story about the end of Oedipus' life. The story is not quite religious, but future set nonetheless, for at least those few lines. Take Revelation as well, circa AD 100. This is certainly religiously prophetic, but denying the elements of fantasy is crazy.

Comment: In fact, from the Bible alone, I can think of at least a handful of prophetic stories that I think should count as "future-set stories".

Comment: I mean, it's right there in the first verse in Rev. 1: "The revelation from Jesus Christ, which God gave him to show his servants what must soon take place." This story is set in the future. Written in about AD 100, John was probably thinking "soon" meant in a life time or two from now.

Comment: I would think futurism (devising stories set in the future) originated coincidentally with whatever brain evolution produced the ability to conceptualize the "future". This happened long before recorded history.

Comment: @TylerH That was the point of my question. Did ancient Egyptians or Hittites or whomever write stories about what they thought the world might be like in 100 years? Is this something that people have been doing since the beginning of recorded history? Or is it an idea that did not come until more recent times?

Comment: @fredsbend Yes, there are prophecies in the Bible, and other ancient religious books, about the future. That's pretty much an essential element of "prophecy": people are rarely impressed when you predict the past. But I was trying to distinguish such predictions from true stories. i.e. "your kingdom will fall to the Babylonians" or "the stock market will fall 10% next year" are not "stories". I had a post earlier where I said how a prediction like this could be phrased as a narrative, so you could run into hazy cases. But still, the idea is fundamentally different. ...

Comment: ... I'm looking for things that could be called "science fiction stories". A prophecy that is, or claims to be, a revelation from God or the gods is not a story in that sense. Just like a financial analyst's predictions about what the market will do next year are not an SF story. And yes, yes, an atheist might say that a religious book is "all a bunch of science fiction". But that's just an insult, not a serious genre definition. Just like if someone says that the Congressional Budget Office's economic predictions are "a bunch of science fiction".

Comment: @Jay That's a pretty broad question, which is my point. Also it's on the verge of off-topic because you're not asking about science-fiction or fantasy, just about a story written in the future.

Comment: @TylerH That was the point in some of the constraints I was trying to put on answers. I was trying to keep it to stories that could be called "science fiction" in at least a broad sense, and exclude warnings and promises and predictions that are not stories.

Comment: I think Revelations is a particularly tricky example.  Even religious scholars are divided as to whether it was intended as a prophecy that certain events would literally come to pass, or whether it was meant as an allegory.  The latter interpretation would put it on a similar footing to science fiction, I'd say - I don't mean that as an insult, I think there actually are parallels.  The fact that Revelations was meant to convey a religious message wouldn't necessarily disqualify it either - there's plenty of SF with religious themes.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure. We're on a tangent here, but: My comment about insults was referring to those who say "it's a bunch of fiction" meaning "I don't believe it's true" when a document is clearly presented as non-fiction. It's certainly true one can write SF with religious themes: James Blish's "A Case of Conscience", many Bradbury stories, etc. Yes, some interpret Revelation as all or partly allegorical. I don't think it has enough narrative to be called a "story", but that's arguable. Whether an allegorical interpretation would give you something that qualifies as SF ...

Comment: ... is getting into definitions. I'd say no, but I'd agree we're getting into edge cases. How much narrative you need for something to be a "story" is debatable too: I've read SF stories presented as a series of memos, or a report sent back to headquarters, that I would call "stories" because of their intended fictional nature. But a series of memos or a report with similar content but presented as true I wouldn't call a "story", even if I thought it was totally false and highly fanciful. (BTW Jesus's parables are clearly presented as fiction. Fiction with a point, of course.)

Comment: Arguably, any sentence beginning with "someday" qualifies....

Comment: Rip van Winkle is set in the past. It was published in 1819 and Rip slept for 20 odd years from before the American Revolution (1775-1783) to after it, awaking in the period of about 1783 to 1795 and possibly during Washington's administration 1789-1797.  If Rip was supposed to wake up after 1819 he would have slept for over 44 years and very few people if any would remember him.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

FuzzyBoots' answer seems like a good one, but it might count as a "religious prophecy"--the description of humanity becoming enfeebled was likely connected to the idea of history going through a cycle of 4 ages known as [Yugas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga) during which the human race becomes increasingly weaker and less virtuous. **Edit:** It also seems January First-of-May's comment on Fuzzyboots' answer is correct, apparently after [Kakudmi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi) was transported forward in time with his daughter [Revati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati) by a period of 27 full cycles of the 4 yugas, Revati was then married to [Balarama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balarama), who was a character that was contemporary with the main war story of the Mahabhrata as mentioned at the top of page 122 of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=w6VWnCzwwZYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA122), so that means that Kakudmi and Revati must have originally come from the distant past.

If you do count it as a religious prophecy, some secular visions of the future can be found in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190509093122/http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/%7Ehbf/sfhist.html):

> The first known fictions even vaguely set in future time are Francis Cheynell's six-page political tract Aulicus: His Dream of the King's Second Coming to London (1644) and Jacques Guttin's Epigone, Story of the Future Century (1659).  Fully developed fictions set in the future would not appear until well into the 18th century.

A bit more on Francis Cheynell's *Aulicus* in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4240643), which says:

> Cheynell is the first dreamer in futuristic fiction. He relates how he fell asleep afflicted by thoughts of the Civil War, and in a protracted nightmare he has a fearful vision of King Charles triumphant over Cromwell and the forces of Parliament. That political fantasy had bite in the May of 1644, when it was still thought possible that the king could prove the victor in the Civil War. With that in mind Cheynell did what so many would go on doing long after him. Within the limitations of six pages he told his tale of the disaster-to-come as dramatically as he could, so that readers would have no doubt that the meaning of his message was: ACT NOW BEFORE IT IS TOO LATE.

Page 9 of the Routledge Companion to Science Fiction, viewable on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=y7CNAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA9), gives a slightly earlier candidate:

> For example, the anonymous English play *A Larum for London* (1602) dramatizes the recent Spanish sack of Antwerp in order, explicitly, to present London with a possible future narrative of Spanish invasion. Time itself appears as a character on stage, exhorting the audience to consider how the future might play out and claiming that he "doth wish to see / No heavy or disastrous chaunce befall / The Sonnes of men, if they will warned be." (Anon. 1913:51)

Not sure if this future was actually dramatized or just described as a dangerous possibility--the [plot description on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Larum_for_London) only talks about the play's depiction of the historical invasion of Antwerp, not the future invasion of England. Likewise the paper [here](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/520752/pdf) (available in full on the paywall-bypassing site sci-hub.tw [here](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1353/pgn.2013.0047)) says that the play "stages events that had happened twenty-three years previously in Antwerp as a stand-in for what might happen if Spain’s ‘Invisible Armada’ were to succeed in sailing up the Thames to London". The full play is available online [here](http://archive.org/details/larumforlondon1600lodguoft), though the spelling and the typeface may make it a bit of chore to read.

Incidentally, if you're curious more generally about narratives of the future predating the well-known 19th century authors like Verne and Wells, I recommend the book [*Origins of Futuristic Fiction*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0820337722) by Paul Alkon.

Answer (score 34):

I like Hypnosifi's answer, but there's a tiny little funny situation that technically counts even if it probably wasn't intended by the OP.

The classic book series [Gargantua and Pantagruel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua_and_Pantagruel), written in the 16th century (first book c. 1532, last book c. 1564), occasionally gives mention of how much time had passed. There is about one specific date in the entire story - an early event is said to have happened in 1420.
As it happens, the author did not seem to take much care of the dates, and when one adds it all up, by the time we get to book four the story is taking place in the early 20th century.
To be fair, I would not have mentioned it at all if the entire thing did not look quite science-fiction-y already (especially in the last two books).

As an aside, there is a 7th century Mayan inscription - part of the West Panel in the Temple of Inscriptions at the tomb of Pakal the Great, in Palenque - that describes the celebration of an anniversary of Pakal's ascension to the throne. Said celebration is supposed to occur in what is the year 4772 by our calendar. The inscription, however, is quite short, and probably not much of a "story" (and, depending on the interpretation, it might also fall under "religious prophecy").

But the above might all be irrelevant, as there is a pretty clear (and rather famous) non-religious science-fictiony passage dating from the 1st century AD:

> There will come an age in the far-off years
> when Ocean shall unloose the bonds of things,
> when the whole broad earth shall be revealed,
> when Tethys shall disclose new worlds
> and Thule not be the limit of the lands.

In case you didn't recognize it (or did but have no idea of the origin, or perhaps only saw it in a different translation), this is from the poem *Medea* by the Roman author Seneca the Younger (specifically, lines 375-379).
This passage (in the original Latin, at least) was famously quoted as prophetic (i.e. referring to the discovery of America) by European explorers ever since Columbus, and comes up in pretty much every book about the Age of Discovery.

And *this* might well be the oldest science fiction set in the future. As far as I know, anyway. (Though, again, it's quite short for a story.)

Comment: For those of us without the benefit of a classical education, would you like to give the source for your 1st century passage?  (And maybe for the 7th century Mayan inscription too.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I do not have much of a classical education either :-) The 1st century passage is quoted in Wikipedia (the article for Thule) as "Seneca: Medea, v. 379" (it's actually lines 375-379); it comes up every so often in discussions of the Age of Discovery. I wasn't able to find a decent source for the Mayan inscription, or I probably would have linked it (most of the discussions i did find had to do with the 2012 thing, which this inscription is said to disprove); but geographically, it's in the West Panel of the Temple of Inscriptions in Palenque (aka the tomb of Pakal the Great).

Comment: @JanuaryFirst-of-May Could you please edit that information into your answer, since comments may be transient?

Comment: The passage by Seneca seems like more a prediction that new lands would be discovered, as an aside in a non-futuristic poem--a footnote [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=I1LEmKPgJ8MC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA260) interprets it as an expression of "the belief — based on the doctrine of the earth's roundness, albeit with all the inconsistencies in measuring the diameter — that there existed inhabited lands, still unreached and unknown." [This book](http://books.google.com/books?id=ttsaAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA165) notes Aristotle similarly postulated an unknown continent on the other side of Earth.

Answer (score 22):

**We simply have no idea.**

Often described as "the hardest problem in science", no one has yet proven when language first developed. There are estimates from millions of years ago to 100,000 years. Likely, shortly after language became common, the first stories were told; But all we can say for certain is that many of our earliest documented stories come from ancient Egypt 4000-2000 BCE. Additionally, while cave art exists all around the globe, many instances dating back 40,000 years, ancient Australian Aboriginal art is considered unique in the story centric nature of many of its drawings; and their mythos contains many "end times" prophecies and stories.

So while it has likely been going on for at least the better part of 100,000 years, the first recorded instances are either religious stories/myths dating sometime around five thousand years ago in Egypt or 20-40 thousand year old Australian cave drawings depicting the apocalypse.

Comment: Okay, I should have said "first known story".

Comment: "first known story to be written down", presumably?

Comment: +1, for the Australian art, but I don't think anyone seriously proposes that language first developed millions of years ago.  The alarm calls of vervet monkeys, for example, are not classed as language.

Comment: I am looking for a list of all books which have been written but which are now completely lost and of which there is no surviving record. :-)

Comment: @Jay Grab yourself a [tag:TARDIS] and go to [Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria)

Answer (score 3):

I would propose [Memoirs of the 20th Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoirs_of_the_Twentieth_Century) as the earliest future fiction work among modern publications. It is the earliest one [listed in Wikipedia for "futures" now past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stories_set_in_a_future_now_past), and also by Randall Munroe (see the XKCD reference by the end of the post).

> This 1733 epistolary novel takes the form of a series of diplomatic letters written in 1997 and 1998. The work is a satire perhaps modeled after Jonathan Swift's Gulliver's Travels published seven years before.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjbkU.png) Madden was an Anglican clergyman, and the book is focused on the dangers of Catholicism and Jesuits, depicting a future where they dominate.
>
> The book was published anonymously, and soon after Madden destroyed most copies. It was little read, and thus had little influence on later writings imagining the future.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjbkU.png)
>
> In his 1987 work Origins of Futuristic Fiction, Paul Alkon describes the book as the earliest of English literature to feature time travel, but notes that it does not explain how it was performed.

For ancient future works, please notice that both the [Epic of Gilgamesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) and [The Iliad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) have parts depicting things happening in the future (from the perspective of their authors, and in the form of prophecies). You may consider the former religious or mythological, but the later is surely secular.

This XKCD comic may be useful:

[image: Stories of the Past and Future]
<sup>Source: https://xkcd.com/1491/</sup>

Comment: If we're looking at "modern publications", is there a reason you would count *Memoirs of the Twentieth Century* (1733) as the first rather than the two earlier ones I mentioned in my answer, *Aulicus: His Dream of the King's Second Coming to London* (1644) and *Epigone, Story of the Future Century* (1659)?

Comment: @Hypnosifl according to your own source, H. Bruce Franklin, the former is a tract, the later an epigone of it. He source goes on to say *"Fully developed fictions set in the future would not appear until well into the 18th century."*

Comment: What do you mean by "an epigone of it"? Are you using a definition of "epigone" that implies something derogatory, less than a "fully developed fiction"? Note that this is a translation of a French title, so we should assume a French definition rather than an English one--I found a discussion [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41482500?seq=1) of the difference, it looks like the French meaning isn't meant to be dismissive in the same way as the English meaning.

Comment: (cont.) I think the "fully developed fictions" comment in the article probably didn't have anything to do with the fact that it was titled an "epigone", maybe the comment was just getting at the idea (which I'm inferring from Alkon's discussion of it in *Origins of Futuristic Fiction*) that the future setting didn't have much impact on the story besides allowing the author to include imagined events different from the real world. In any case, the original question just asks for any type of fictional story set in the author's future.